# Deploying Django as standalone internal app?

Tags: django, iis, wsgi, django-haystack, cherrypy

I'm developing an tool using Django for internal use at my organization. It's used to search and tag documents (using Haystack and Solr), and will be employed on different projects. My team currently has a working prototype and we want to deploy it 'in the wild.'

Our security environment is strict. Project documents are located on subfolders on a network drive, and access to these folders is restricted based on users' Windows credentials (we also have an MS SQL server that uses the same credentials). A user can only access the projects they are involved in. Since we're an exclusively Microsoft shop, if we want to deploy our app on the company intranet, we'll need to use an IIS server to deal with these permissions. No one on the team has the requisite knowledge to work with IIS, Active Directory, and our IT department is already over-extended. In short, we're not web developers and we don't have immediate access to anybody experienced.

My hacky solution is to forgo IIS entirely and have each end user run a lightweight server locally (namely, CherryPy) while each retaining access to a common project-specific database (e.g. a SQLite DB living on the network drive or a DB on the MS SQL server). In order to use the tool, they would just launch an all-in-one batch script and point their browser to `127.0.0.1:8000`. I recognize how ugly this is, but I feel like it leverages the security measures already in place (note that never expect more than 10 simultaneous users on a given project). Is this a terrible idea, and if so, what's a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've dealt with a similar situation (primary development was geared toward a normal deployment situation, but some users have a requirement to use the application on a standalone workstation). Rather than deploy web and db servers on a standalone workstation, I just run the app with the Django internal development server and a SQLite DB. I didn't use CherryPy, but hopefully this is somewhat useful to you.

My current solution makes a nice executable for users not familiar with the command line (who also have trouble remembering the URL to put in their browser) but is also relatively easy development:

1. Use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) to package up the Django app into single executable. Once you figure this out, don't continue to do it by hand, add it to your continuous integration system (or at least write a script).
2. Modify the `manage.py` to:

   - Detect if the app is `frozen` by PyInstaller and there are no arguments (i.e.: user executed it by double clicking it) and if so, then run `execute_from_command_line(..)` with arguments to start the Django development server.
   - Right before running the `execute_from_command_line(..)`, pop off a thread that does a `time.sleep(2)` (to let the development server come up fully) and then `webbrowser.open_new("http://127.0.0.1:8000")`.
3. Modify the app's `settings.py` to detect if frozen and change things around such as the path to the DB server, enabling the development server, etc.

A couple additional notes.

- If you go with SQLite, [Windows file locking on network shares may not be adequate](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5) if you have concurrent writing to the DB; concurrent readers should be fine. Additionally, since you'll have different DB files for different projects you'll have to figure out a way for the user to indicate which file to use. Maybe prompt in app, or build the same app multiple times with different `settings.py` files. Variety of a ways to hit this nail...
- If you go with MSSQL (or any client/server DB), the app will have to know the DB credentials (which means they could be extracted by a knowledgable user). This presents a security risk that may not be acceptable. Basically, don't try to have the only layer of security within the app that the user is executing. The DB credentials used by the app that a user is executing should only have the access that the user is allowed.